# Efficient way to setup Jenkins for Automation Project

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have configured Jenkins server on windows computer. The systems has below configurations:

> **OS** : Windows 10
>
> **Processor** : intel i3 processor
>
> **RAM** : 16GB
>
> 500GB hard disk

The problem is recently the system get crashed and now windows is unable to start. Lastly, I set up an automated test execution on 3 parallel Chrome browser instances in GUI mode for 2 hours. It gets crashed during the execution. I'm not sure whether this happened due to a lack of sufficient resources or these are adequate configuration resources to handle the execution.

Can someone please share the realistic configuration required to handle such a situation or manage the resources in an efficient way. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 3 chrome browser doesn't eat up resources. That's a normal use case

Comment: What error are you getting. When try to start windows ?  Blue screen error ? Then windows os might have got corrupted with some updates

Comment: @PDHide, `PXE-E32: TFTP open timeout ?` its unable to boot

Comment: PXE-E32 is method to boot a OS from the network. I think message is normal, but you could try to disable PXE in the bios. Probably the harddisk is broken and it now tries other boot options like PXE. More info on PXE https://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/definition/Preboot-Execution-Environment

Comment: Thanks @NielsvanReijmersdal for the information. I'm curious why this execution cause crash

Comment: Maybe the machine got to hot? Sounds like a hardware problem. Could also be a memory-leak in the application. I recently had a web-app using 4GB of memory :)

Answer (score 0):

Your machine is capable to run Jenkins and some tests in parallel.

Jenkins Requirements:

> Recommended hardware configuration for a small team:
>
> 1 GB+ of RAM
>
> 50 GB+ of drive space
>
> https://jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/

Three Chrome instances take maybe 250MB memory each. Depends on the web-application, some take rediculeuse amounts of memory, but SQA.SE for example takes 50MB.

Answer (score 0):

In continuous integration testing like jenkins the configuration mentioned by you is enough to install the Jenkins and execute the test on your machine.
As you are using 3 parallels chrome instance for the execution this might be the reason for the window crash.
It would be great if you initially test with one chrome and then increase the parallels browser count one by one so that you can check the upper limit of your machine to execute test in parallels.